# Excel finance app Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, excel, string, transactions, finance

I'm making an excel finance calculator and the columns I've chosen are the ones I need in my calculation, the app takes the start date and the end date from the user and then calculate all the transaction amount between those dates and I get this error that stops the app

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Input.ExcelReader.main(ExcelReader.java:81)
package Input;





public class ExcelReader {

  public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\abdo\\Downloads\\Sample File.xlsx";
  static double CreditTRX = 0 ;   
  static double DebitTRX = 0.0 ;  
  static int noDebitTRX = 0 ; 
  static int cashAtHand = 0  ;  
  static double agentComm = 0.0 ; 
  static double Amount = 0.0 ;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));


        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();





        //entering dates 
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Please enter the start date ");
             String d1 = in.next();    

             System.out.print("Please enter the end date ");
             String d2 = in.next(); 

                int  M1 = 0 ;  int D1 = 0 ; 
                int M2 = 0 ;   int D2 = 0 ; 

              String date1[] = d1.split("/");
              M1 = Integer.parseInt(date1[0]);

              D1 = Integer.parseInt(date1[1]);

              String date2[] = d2.split("/");
                  M2 = Integer.parseInt(date2[0]);
                  D2 = Integer.parseInt(date2[1]);

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
             Row row = rowIterator.next();


                Cell trxType = row.getCell(3) ;
                String Type = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(trxType);

                Cell trxAmount = row.getCell(8) ; 
                String sAmount = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(trxAmount) ; 


                Cell trxDate = row.getCell(13) ;
                String Date = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(trxDate);

            //date equalizer

            Date = Date.replaceAll("/18", "/2018");
            Date = Date.replaceAll("2018/", "18/") ;
            if (!Date.equals("Trx Date"))  {



         String tempDate[] = Date.split("/");
         int tempMonth = Integer.parseInt(tempDate[0]);
         int tempDay = Integer.parseInt(tempDate[1]);


                   if ( M2 == M1   ) {

                                if ((tempDay <= D1) && (tempDay >= D2) ) {

                                    total(sAmount,Type) ; 

                                }
                   }else if  (M2 > M1) {

                       if ((tempMonth <= M1) && (tempMonth >= M2) && tempMonth!= M2 ) {

                                    total(sAmount,Type) ;  

                                }else if (tempMonth ==  M2 ) {

                                     if ((tempDay <= D1) && (tempDay >= D2) ) {

                                        total(sAmount,Type) ;  

                                     }

                                }

                   }


            }

}


        double CashAtHand = DebitTRX ; 

         agentComm = noDebitTRX *0.75 ; 

          System.out.println("Total number of DebitTRX =" + noDebitTRX);
          System.out.println("Total CreditTRX Amount =" + CreditTRX);
          System.out.println("Total DebitTRX Amount =" + DebitTRX);
          System.out.println("Cash at hand =" + cashAtHand);
          System.out.println("Total agent commssion =" + agentComm);





    }


    public static void total ( String s , String t ) {  

     if(s.equals("Amount") ){
         System.out.println(s);

       }

       else if(!s.equals("Amount") && !s.equals(null) ) {
        s=s.replaceAll("," , "") ;
        System.out.println(s);
        Amount = Double.valueOf(s) ; 

       }

       if (t.equals("Debit")) {
        noDebitTRX++ ;
        DebitTRX = DebitTRX + Amount ; 
       }
       else if (t.equals("Reverse Debit")) {
        noDebitTRX--;
        DebitTRX = DebitTRX - Amount ; 
       }
       else if (t.equals("Notify Credit")) {
        CreditTRX = CreditTRX + Amount ;
       }

    }
```

}

I think the errors comes from the while loop ( .hasnext() ) but I couldn't solve it

Sorry If the post isn't proper cause I'm new to the site and coding in general

Comment: Try debugging what is there in tempDate and please share the same here.

Comment: I debugged and It enters the total method and gets the sAmount in double as wanted but it doesn't enter the other if statements to add the sAmount but this isn't where the error happens the errors happen after it finishes  all the rows

Comment: I found that the < , > signs were reversed but the null error is still there

Comment: thank you I found the error, I added this if statement and everything worked well  if (!Date.equals("")) {
             String tempDate[] = Date.split("/");
              tempMonth = Integer.parseInt(tempDate[0]);
              tempDay = Integer.parseInt(tempDate[1]);
                }